# RecordTypes and Dynamic Page Layouts

Tags: page-layout, record-type

Is it possible to change the visibility of the fields on a page layout based off of a RecordType?

I understand that I can change the page layout for different object for different profiles but I don't want to do that. I want to hide certain fields if they aren't relevant to that record type. Is something dynamic like this possible?

Comment: what object are you working on for this? Have you looked at [dynamic forms](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2019/break-up-your-record-details-with-dynamic-forms)? It's [currently available only for custom objects](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brox), however.

Comment: the Account object so sadly it's not custom @KrisGoncalves

Comment: I think right now you have the options of multiple layouts mapped for different record types via the profile, or a custom form (e.g. an LWC) to handle this. In later platform releases you'll have dynamic forms as KrisGoncalves said.

Comment: thanks @PhilW i think this is the best path for now as well. if you want to write this as the answer i will mark it as correct.